# How to combine multiple scopes with OR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6

I have three scopes

```
scope :a, -> { where("first_name like 'A%'") }
scope :b, -> { where("first_name like 'B%'") }
scope :c, -> { where("first_name in ('Charles','Chris')") }
```

I want to merge these three scopes and create a new scope like

```
scope :combined_abc, -> { where("first_name like 'A%'") or 
                          where("first_name like 'B%'") or 
                          where("first_name in ('Charles','Chris')") 
                        }
```

I am looking for a clean and nice way to pre-define the big scope rather than using three OR conditions in the SQL.

My ultimate goal is to delete the users whose first names start with "a", "b" or first name is 'Charles' or 'Chris'.

`user.combined_abc.destory_all`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is Postgres. Just tagged. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails supports `#or` for ActiveRecord::Relation from 5.

```
scope :combined_abc, -> { a.or(b).or(c) }
```

Note: `a`/`b`/`c` must be structurally compatible.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine them using regexp:

```
scope :combined_abc, -> { where("first_name like '[A-C]%'")}
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer. I just updated the third condition to an array. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use regular expressions:

```
where first_name ~ '^(A|B|Charles|Chris)'
```

You should be able to write this as:

```
where("first_name ~ '^(A|B|Charles|Chris)")
```

Comment: how can I translate it to Ruby Active Record Query Interface? scope :combined_abc, -> { where("first_name ~ '^(A|B|Charles|Chris)'") }?